# Java Socket - BufferedReader lost data

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, readline, synchronized

I'm making java chatting program

I read log in Server, and send it to Client

First, I tested in **Server**

```
public synchronized void SendLogLine(String time, String sender, String fontSize, String fontColor, String fontStyle, String msg) {
        System.out.println(time + "\t" + sender + "\t" + fontSize + "\t" + fontColor + "\t" + fontStyle + "\t" + msg);
        roomSocketWriter.println("Start Sending Log");
        roomSocketWriter.println(time);
        roomSocketWriter.println(sender);
        roomSocketWriter.println(fontSize);
        roomSocketWriter.println(fontColor);
        roomSocketWriter.println(fontStyle);
        roomSocketWriter.println(msg);
        roomSocketWriter.println(delimiter);
    }
```

If I print information, Server's console shows like this

`[14-11-01 00:06:00]    room    13    black    0    user_exits`

However, if I print same thing in Client, it doesn't have some data.

Here is **Client's code**

```
String input = roomSocketReader.readLine();
                while(!input.equals("end of log")) {
                    System.out.println(input);
                    input = roomSocketReader.readLine();
                }
```

And here is the **Result of Print**

```
black
0
user_exits





user_entered
delimiter
Start Sending Log


















13
black
0
user_entered
delimiter
Start Sending Log
[14-11-01 09:37:26]
room
13
black
0
user_exits
delimiter
```

As you see, many data is lost :(
(empty line is lost data)

Does anyone know reason and solution?

===================================================================================

I found where **Client** stops

I tried debug.

When doing the first line of **Client** -> `String input = roomSocketReader.readLine();`

debug line goes via

```
public String readLine() throws IOException {
    return readLine(false);   <- HERE
}
```

and stops at here!

```
String readLine(boolean ignoreLF) throws IOException {
StringBuffer s = null;
int startChar;
boolean omitLF = ignoreLF || skipLF;

    synchronized (lock) {    <- EXACTLY DEBUG LINE DISAPPEARS AT HERE!
        ensureOpen();
```

Comment: Are there multiple threads using the same socket in parallel?

Comment: There is no 2 threads which use same socket. Only functions in same thread share socket.